# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to insert multiple data into mongoDB. Data comes from another web service in JSON format. I collect that data and store in my DB. But, when I am trying to iterate over collected items, I get Type Error as mentioned in Question.

```
// Add purchase details to DB (Userid, Productid, Category)
router.post('/addpurchased', function(req, res){
    // Connect to the server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the Server:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Connected to Server',url);


    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('purchased');

    var arrProducts = req.body.products;
    var userProducts = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arrProducts.length; i++){
      // Get the purchased details passed from the form
      var user = {userid: arrProducts[i].userid, productid: arrProducts[i].productid, category: arrProducts[i].category,
         purchasetime: new Date()};

      userProducts.push(user);
    }

    // Insert the purchase data into the database
    collection.insert(userProducts, function (err, result){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send("Purchase Details Added")
      }
    });
  }
});

});
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

I am passing JSOM data from postman as below, [image]

and get error message as below.
[image]

Comment: What's the content of `arrProducts`? Set a breakpoint in the next line and check in your debugger what arrProducts contains. You will see that it's undefined. So most likely no data has been submitted in the request body for `products`

Comment: Apparently your `req.body.products` is `undefined` which means you don't pass `products` to your API method properly

Comment: what is the output of this arrProducts[] ?

Comment: arrProducts was not having any content. I have updated the question, please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in comments, your req.body.products is comming in null. This will fix your error, but then you need to figure out why you are not getting products.

```
 var arrProducts = [];
  if(req && req.body && req.body.products){
   var arrProducts = req.body.products;
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < arrProducts.length; i++){
  // Get the purchased details passed from the form
  var user = {userid: arrProducts[i].userid, productid: arrProducts[i].productid, category: arrProducts[i].category,
     purchasetime: new Date()};

  userProducts.push(user);
}
```

You can do that by printing out the contents of body to debug or

```
console.log(req.body);
```

Comment: Not `null`, but `undefined`

Comment: @camccar , yes it was undefined, I am passing data from postman, but have an issue three, please see if that can be rectified.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong JSON format in postman.
Use inverted commas in JSON format as request requires it to be as a string.

If you will use this from Javascript XHR request you need to use JSON.stringify(object) before sending request to server.

```
{ 
"products": [
       {
        "productid" : "first",
        "userid" : "1",
        "category": "edu"
       },
       {
        "productid" : "second",
        "userid" : "2",
        "category": "edu"
       }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the leads. I was not passing JSON data properly. Now it works fine.